Calculate standard deviation of average duration of last 1 day to last 30 days
I'm trying to find the standard deviation of average duration in a table for the last 1 day as compared to the last 30 days average duration.
let table1 = view() { 
requests | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) | summarize AvgDuration1d = avg(duration) by itemtype };
let table2 = view() { 
requests | where TimeGenerated > ago(30d) | summarize AvgDuration1d = avg(duration) by itemtype };
table1 | join kind=leftouter table2 on itemtype

This above query gives me average duration of both 1 day and 30 days in the same query. Now I need to find the standard deviation between the two.
Any insights may be helpful. TIA!

Have you tried using division @vpn?


KQL - Calculate standard deviation of average duration of last 1 day to last 30 days

You can use below KQL query to achieve that:
let rith1 = requests
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2d)
| summarize Avg1d = avg(duration) by itemtype;
let rith2 = requests
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| summarize Avg30d = avg(duration) by itemtype;
rith1
| join kind=inner (rith2) on itemtype
| extend rith_md = (Avg1d + Avg30d) / 2
| extend ri_var = pow(Avg1d - rith_md, 2) + pow(Avg30d - rith_md, 2)
| extend Standard_Deviation = sqrt(ri_var/2)
| project itemtype, Avg1d, Avg30d, Standard_Deviation

Here, I have done for 2 days to 30 days(because of my data. You can do for 1 to 30 days).
Output:

Fiddle

Thank you for your inputs. However, when I use the same query in Workbooks, these values are getting multiplied by 1000. Do you have any idea?

No I did not got my values multiplied by 1000. Are you following my complete query?

If they are getting multiplied by 1000, check at which line they are getting use  division by 1000 as /1000, so that it will be correct

Nope, same query works in Monitor but returns different results in Workbook

Then do as I suggested in above statement, use division by 1000 where it is getting multiplied
